# Make sharp dashed line path stroke on rounded corners in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Following [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-to-get-dashed-line-in-photoshop/245#245), I've tried to make rounded corners with dashed stroke, but the output is blurry. Is there any method to make a sharp dashed stroke in Photoshop?

Comment: using what tools?

Comment: I'm not clear what "The summary is blurry" means.

Comment: @pnj4: I think there is a language barrier here. If you upload your image to a public location on the web, I will be happy to add a link in your question. @e100: I think "summary" means "result" in this context. @DA01: The question is tagged with `adobe-photoshop`, unless you put it there.

Comment: Philip you understood right i guess he is saying about output @pnj4 please rollback if i am wrong...

Comment: @pnj4 - Do you have access to Adobe Illustrator?  It's not a pure-Photoshop solution, but it would save you much time to create a stroked path in illustrator and copy it into Photoshop.

Comment: @DA01: Adobe Photoshop CS4

Comment: @e100: it means the result & I've uploaded to [here](http://d.pr/yVu0)

@Philip Reagan: Yes uploaded to [here](http://d.pr/yVu0)

@Farray: I have Illustrator too but I have very little knowledge in Illustrator :D

@all: sorry for VERY LATE reply ;)

Comment: Post you own answer how you did it and accept it as right answer let everyone know how you achieved this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have access to Illustrator, the easiest way to do a dashed stroke is to create the stroked shape in Illustrator and copy/paste it into Photoshop.

Since you're unfamiliar with AI, here's a quick step-by-step:

1. Use the `Rectangle Tool (M)` to create your shape:
   [image]
   [image]
2. With your shape selected, `Effect` ⇒ `Stylize` ⇒ `Round Corners...`
   [image]
3. With your shape still selected, Open your `Stroke` palette and set the `Dashed Line` attributes to your liking.
   [image]
4. You now have a shape with a dashed stroke.  Copy it and paste into Photoshop.  If Photoshop asks how you want to paste, choose "as pixels".
   [image]

Note on above:  Illustrator's display will likely anti-alias your shape.  If you screengrab and then paste into Photoshop, you will still have "blurry" problems.  If you copy and paste the object itself, you will not have this issue.  You should also keep your shape dimensions in whole-pixel increments to avoid Photoshop anti-aliasing when it pastes the pixels.

Comment: he already mentioned his answer farry....

Answer (score 0):

Pulling in a vector from illustrator is the best way to go like Farray said. Sometimes I will take a screen shot of my object selected and paste and cut it out with the selection. Unfortunately it is rasterized and not customizable.

Comment: Welcome to GD! For future reference, your answer would probably work better as comment (once you have more reputation to post comments)

Answer (score -1):

Dear Pnj4 its just an assumption not a real answer just to give you a little help,

> kindly attach a screenshot or anything
>   to get  proper answer

As you already created your rounded corner with dash line stroke, where ever i know your stretching or by mistake made it wrong that's why its getting blurry, try to recreate your steps carefully might be you'll get your real output without any blur and all. i am listing some tutorial for you i doubt you made mistake  with brush presets.

1. [Dotted Line Border](http://www.pssimply.com/photoshop/3/dotted-line-border.html) this will help you i am sure.
2. [How to dash line](http://www.planetphotoshop.com/dashed-lines-in-photoshop.html)
3. [3 Easy method to create dotted lines](http://www.ianhoar.com/2011/05/28/3-easy-methods-to-create-dotted-or-dashed-lines-in-photoshop/)