# How do I make dotted borders in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

How do I make dotted borders around my custom layer. Now I have a simple rectangle that I want to have with a dotted line (dash 1px, gap 6px). How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make better dashed line path stroke?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/make-better-dashed-line-path-stroke)

Comment: Wait for CS6 it has dotted lines. Woo Hoo! =>

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do it, but the least tedious method is to use brushes. With brushes, you'll have perfect control over the width, thickness, and spacing of your dotted line.

Check out **[THIS LINK](http://www.pssimply.com/photoshop/3/dotted-line-border.html)** for more specific instructions.

Comment: -1 for dead link.

Answer (score 1):

For a 1-pixel dot you need the Pencil tool, which lives under the Brush tool in the Tools panel.

Follow the steps in the tutorial Jon referenced, with these changes:

1. Choose a 1-pixel Pencil.
2. In the Brush panel, under Brush Tip Shape, set the spacing to 700%.
3. When you choose "Stroke Path" be sure to turn OFF the "Simulate Pressure" checkbox.

As you see from the screen grab, you'll still have odd spacing at the corners, but there's no easy way around that inside PS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have inDesign you can follow these easy steps:

1. Copy your layer to an new inDesign document
2. Add a dotted stroke to the document http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6bfba.html
3. import the document in photoshop by drag 'n drop. Select "smart object" if you wan't to resize it later.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Open this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dm6baub1a7kokdx/Stroke.psd) in photoshop and..

1. go to `Edit > Define Pattern`
2. Name the pattern
3. double click the layer on which you want to add the stroke
4. select `stroke` in the `layer style` window
5. select `pattern` on the fill type option
6. select the pattern (adjust size, scaling if needed)
   thats it!! have fun!