# Designing a clothing company Tag

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, software-recommendation, print-production, dieline

Can anyone tell me which is the best software for Designing a clothing company Tag?

Also any preferred/standard size (if any) or special requirements for designing a tag?

Comment: Hi Designmate, can you tell us what part you are stuck on? Are you having trouble designing the actual design or laying out the design multiple times on a page for printing? Also asking for best software is a little too broad as this process could be done on a wide variety of programs. Also the type of tag you create will determine the size the tag needs to be.

Comment: Yes, actually I needed to create a tag(and doing it for the first time) and don't know what size will be fine. Also, I want to know that in designing a dress tag do we also put a bar code alongwith the sizes of the dress. Any other suggestions what all we should write on a tag designed for dress??

Comment: Yes, actually I needed to create a tag(and doing it for the first time) and don't know what size will be fine. Also, I want to know that in designing a dress tag do we also put a bar code alongwith the sizes of the dress?? Any other suggestions what all we should write on a tag designed for dress?? By the way I started it in illustrator. Also are the tags are cut off manually after printing (This part of question is not mandatory, but still any knowledge on this part will be greatly appreciated). I have searched & got a size for tag as : Max. height: 75 mm and Max. width: 165 mm.

Comment: The best software is the software you prefer and that is also compatible with what the printer needs/wants.

Comment: This is to broad. Use whatever you want and as DA01 points out.. the printer accepts. I've traditionally used Illustrator, but that's by no mean the *only* option.

Comment: @Scott, DA01 : U guys have yourself answered my question firstly and now u are putting it on hold. See, I really don't know what's the way out. I am a new user in stack exchange. I thought this site to be really nice and members as helpful. But, I don't know why u guys are putting my questions on hold. Just wanted to receive and give knowledge and help in return. If u guys really want to help out then please tell me how to ask questions, as presently because of your on hold questions, I am not able to ask further questions. Before asking a question, I always check if there is an answer already

Comment: Designmate... comments are not intended to be answers. The comment field is to seek clarification or explain voting. My response with explaining *why* I voted to close this question..... it is too broad and open-ended with no possible way to **definitively** answer it. All answers would be merely *opinions*. That doesn't make for a good Stack Exchange question. There's no harm in it though. It's just not a great question for a Q&A site. Remember, this is **not** a "forum" like you may be used to.

Comment: @Scott: I understood it's not a forum. I actually have seen more broad question in this site than mine. But, why are they not closed still?? I have seen some Q&A's which are very much lengthy, but again they are never closed. But u know what I feel is that many times in order to exchange knowledge we can actually help some. All the comments to me has point of learning in it, whether it be your's or anyone else :) By the way no point of hurting from my side. I ask without hurting anyone or violating any rules. But I really don't think that this question is too broad :)

Comment: @ Scott :Also Sometimes for a person a question can b answered in a single line, but sometimes for another person the same is satisfactory and understandable in detailed explanation. I believe those all who give their answers in order to explain the topic asked are taking out their precious time to help others. Which is commendable effort.

Comment: @ Scott : By the way, I would appreciate if you could tell me how and when can I start asking my questions again????

Comment: You need to create the tag as any other project with a dieline (there's a hole). Size depends on your own preference & budget! Barcodes are usually OVERPRINTED by another machine, so you need to simply keep a white area free for this barcode later on your tag. You need to investigate what system you'll use for all this; for lot of products, you'll need to print the tag twice: once for the main layout, once for the barcode. For small shops, each tag can have the barcode printed with design. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57614/creating-in-ps-a-bleed-for-a-die-cut-sticker?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Standard tag sizes**

The size of the tag will depend on the type of tag you want to make, see examples [Clothing Tag Design Guide](http://www.qualitywovenlabels.com/design.htm). You could create any size tag that you want (if you're printing yourself). It is best to contact a printer for sizes if you're printing the tags or getting them embroidered somewhere else.

One example of a standard tag from the above link is 1.25" W x 2.5" H. This is the tag dimensions and not the working art area (I couldn't find any definitive answers for a "standard" tag size).

**Putting the bar code**

The bar code will most likely go on a separate tag. These tags differ in that the clothing tag is for sizes and the price tag is something that you can detach from the dress.

**What to put on the tag**

This is an opinion question as you could put whatever you want. I have usually seen the companies logo and the other side is washing instructions.

Comment: HI AndrewH. A big thanks to u for sharing your knowledge with me. your guidance really helped me a lot. Thank you so much. It feels good to see, that there are persons who can understand how much a little of their guidance/help can be a bliss in someone's life. Again thanks mate :)