# How to put a dotted line stroke on a vector shape using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, stroke

I've created a simple vector pennant type banner using Photoshop. I'd like to put a stroke on the banner with dashed lines approximately 3 pixels in from the edges of the shape. I know I can add a stroke to the shape and that looks fine, but I want to position the stroke so that there is a space of about 3 pixels between the edge of the pennant and the stroke. Is there a way to do that using Photoshop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make sharp dashed line path stroke on rounded corners in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/make-sharp-dashed-line-path-stroke-on-rounded-corners-in-photoshop)

Comment: the above posted link shows how to add a dashed/dotted line in Photoshop thanks to the answer by Farray.  If that doesnt answer your question please consider adding pictures to show your issue.  Other questions that may help are: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-to-get-dashed-line-in-photoshop/245#245

Answer (score 3):

If this **must** be done in Photoshop, you will need 2 separate shapes. One for the outer shape and one for the offset inner stroke.

[image: photoshop]

With Illustrator you can use the `Offset Path` effect to move a stroke to the inside of a shape. You could then copy/paste the shape to Photoshop as a smart object.

[image: AI]

Comment: How do you even "open" the part showing the stroke options? I don't see a way to set the stroke options.

Comment: @Pacerier - To see the stroke options you need to; 1) Make sure your object is vector, and 2) Select the layer your object is on (the one you want to apply a stroke to), then click on the Direct Selection Tool in your Tools palette. This will display the stroke options for your selected object/layer. Hope that helps!