# How to draw curved lines inside a badge in PhotoShop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I have a badge and I want to draw dash line inwards. So far I have tried some methods like using Pen to draw and "Convert Point Tool", but I cannot make it right, and it's hard to explain, please take a look my screenshot .

Please help.

[image]

To make myself more clear, I want to the dash line inside the badge near to its sides like this one.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “dash line inwards”, exactly?

Comment: hi @JanusBahsJacquet please see my update. thanks

Comment: Can't you just select the badge, shrink the selection, and then add a stroke (like in the last screenshot)?

Comment: hi @JanusBahsJacquet  I do not know how to add a stroke. I checked the screenshot web page, it's for illustrator not PS. I am an novice.

Comment: This is impossible to do outside illustrator. because illustrator know how to deal with the dashed line when it meet curves and corners.

Comment: @Franva, this is possible in pure css http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/stitched-look/ if you want to avoid PS & AI. You may also need http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

Comment: wow, that's really cool~! thanks @Christopher . But is PS capable of doing it?

Comment: I saw PS can do stitch effect on simple shapes but not this complicated

Comment: Have you read http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-to-get-dashed-line-in-photoshop and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20327/how-to-put-a-dotted-line-stroke-on-a-vector-shape-using-photoshop and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/make-sharp-dashed-line-path-stroke-on-rounded-corners-in-photoshop ?

Comment: hi @Christopher thank you for the information you provided. It's helpful :) The last 2 are for adding stitch on simple shapes, not for my case. I will try the last one. :)

Comment: I found those in 2 mins of googling; many more off-site results too.